# How do I cancel a Promise.all() in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I currently have a sign up process and on each next click a Promise.all() is made, which calls a lot of http requests.  If the client goes through very quickly (pressing next buttons very fast) all of the http request build up and it messes up my app.

Is there a way I can cancel a Promise.all() so that if they click next and the previous Promise.all() is still running I can just cancel it?

Comment: promises are not cancelable. there was a spec in working to make them so but the work on it was stopped.

Comment: @toskv So, promises are not cancelable, but the spec to make promises cancelable was itself evidently cancelable.

Comment: @JeffBowman sadly it was very cancelable. :(

Comment: @georgej Can you clarify how the promises are messing up your app?

Answer (score 4):

You can wait for promises to finish, but you can't cancel them.

You could disable the following next button until they have all completed.

`<button [disabled]="completed">Next</button>`

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that "cancel a Promise.all()" means "ensure that the promise returned by a Promise.all() does not follow its success path" ....

Promises are not cancelable, but pattern-based solution(s) are available.

The concept here is reasonably simple. Essentially, in each batch of promises you can include a promise that :

- will be resolved if the raw batch is successful
- will be rejected on creation of the next batch.

It's a kind of race of good against evil.

The hard part is making the "super-aggregation" transparent to the results.

Here's one way to write it - maybe not the most concise - someone may spot a better way.

```
function BatchCanceller() {
    // Return a function, which accepts an array of promises and returns an aggregated promise.
    // Use the returned function like $q.all().
    var dfrd;
    return function(promises) {
        if(dfrd) {
            dfrd.reject(new Error('cancelled')); // reject previous batch
        }
        dfrd = $q.defer();
        // Preparation; ensure that `promises`, if all are successful, resolve `dfrd`.
        $q.all(promises).then(dfrd.resolve);
        // Now include `dfrd` in a super-aggregation of `promises`
        return $q.all(promises.concat(dfrd.promise)) // Will the aggregated `promises` resolve before another batch causes `dfrd.reject()`?
        .then(function(results) {
            // Yay! the aggregated `promises` won out.
            return results.splice(0, results.length-1); // remove the unwanted extra result.
        }); // no need to handle error here
    };
}

var batchCanceller = new BatchCanceller();

var promises = [/* whatever */];
batchCanceller(promises).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // message is "cancelled" if another `batchCanceller(promises)` is executed before the previous one resolves.
});
```

In practice, you would probably choose to express `BatchCanceller()` as an Angular factory.

Answer (score 0):

I would use observables, `switchMap` and `debounceTime`, something like

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  actions: Observable<any[]>;
  private signals = new Subject<string>();
  constructor() {}

  submit(signal: string): void {
    this.signals.next(signal);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actions = this.signals
      .debounceTime(300)        
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(signal => {
         // make http calls with the signal e.g
         // return this.service.getAction(signal)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
      });
  }
}
```

Which is based on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#-_observable-s

A nice thing about `switchMap` is it will cancel any in flight http requests if another signal comes through. That being said if your server doesn't handle cancelled requests, it doesn't help much.

Comment: Does this solution not depend on that hard-coded `.debounceTime(300)` being an appropriate model of whatever is being debounced? In the OP's case, what if his `$q.all()` took longer than 300 ms to settle?

Comment: Hmm I might have misunderstood the question, I thought the OP wanted to reduce app server workload, i.e the backend. Why would multiple http requests mess up the frontend angular app?

Comment: I think you might understand that from the first paragraph of the question, but not the second. Have another read and see if you agree.

Comment: I still don't understand :/ I've asked the OP to clarify

Comment: Good idea. Let's see what he says.